# convert RGB int value to Hex format with 0x prefix in c#

Tags: c#, hex, rgb, colordialog

I am trying to convert an RGB value to hex format in c# using this code :

```
int ColorValue = Color.FromName("mycolor").ToArgb();
string ColorHex = string.Format("{0:x6}", ColorValue);
```

The `colorHex` value likes this format `ffffff00` but i need to change it like this :`0x0000`.how can i do that?

Best regards

I am so new in c# form application .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the `0x` part yourself in the format string:

```
// Local variable names to match normal conventions.

// Although Color doesn't have ToRgb, we can just mask off the top 8 bits,
// leaving RGB in the bottom 24 bits.
int colorValue = Color.FromName("mycolor").ToArgb() & 0xffffff;
string colorHex = string.Format("0x{0:x6}", colorValue);
```

If you want capital hex values instead of lower case, use `"0x{0:X6}"` instead.

Comment: Thanks Jon .but i got this error:{System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormat(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)

Comment: @EA: Uh, where? That doesn't happen in the code I've provided. If you *also* want it to be in upper case (which is what Steve's answer does) you should have specified that...

Comment: It was my fault ,but your method gives me this result :0xff008080

Comment: @EA: Ah, I see. That's easily fixed. See my edit. You don't need to do the arithmetic manually as per Steve's answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only the 3 bytes that define the RGB part of the color you could try this

```
    Color c = Color.FromName("mycolor");
    int ColorValue = (c.R * 65536) + (c.G * 256) + c.B;
    string ColorHex = string.Format("0x{0:X6}", ColorValue);
```